# C++ Multithreading Run function on main thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have a thread with a TCP Socket that connects to a server and waits for data in a while loop, so the thread never ends. When the socket receives data, it is parsed, and based on the opcode of the packet, should call x function. Whats the fastest/best way to go about that?

I read around that doing some kind of task/message queue system is a way of doing it, but not sure if there is any better options.

Should mention that I can not use boost:

Edit: Sorry, half asleep haha.

Here is the loop from thread x:

```
while (Running)
{
    if (client.IsConnected())
    {
        Recieve();
    }
    FPlatformProcess::Sleep(0.01);
}
```

In the Receive function, it parses the data, and based on the packet opcode, I need to be able to call a function on the main thread (the GUI thread), because a lot of the packets are to spawn GUI objects, and I can't create GUI objects from any other thread than the main one.

So basically: I have a main thread, that spawns a new thread that enters a loop, listens for data, and I need to be able to call a function from the 2nd thread that runs on the main thread.

Comment: Please show us the code for the thread with the TCP socket.

Comment: "should call x function. Whats the fastest/best way to go about that?" Simple: `x();` I assume there is more to your question than immediately meets the eye, but it's not at all clear what that might be.

Comment: Use an existing framework like RPC, SOAP, XMLRPC, COM etc. Rolling your own system is a bad idea. Also, whenever you ask for something like "best", you first have to define what **your** criteria are.

Comment: My question isn't about the data. I have a main thread, that spawns a new thread that enters a loop, listens for data, and I need to be able to call a function from the 2nd thread that runs on the main thread. Best = fastest in my case.

Comment: Why do you need the function to run on the main thread?

Comment: Because I can't create GUI objects from any other thread other than the main thread.

Comment: A typical GUI framework would have some means of queuing a message or event to a UI thread. E.g. `PostMessage` in Windows, a signal with `QueuedConnection` in Qt. Figure out what it is for the framework you use.

Comment: It's actually Unreal Engine 4, a game engine